# Display Product Detail When Click a Button returning false

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm comming up with a problem when i want to display a div Pop-up that appears when users click a button returning false. This mean I can't find ways to display a product detail in div pop-up without loading a page again.

I'm looking for a solution like this and any relevant ways. 
Here is my code:

Explain:

- $product_list is used for displaying products and $product_list2 is used for display div Popup.
- Button With Onclick Add_to_cart() will return false and change div_top1 from display: none to display: block.

  ```
  <?php
  include 'Config.php';
  $product_list = "";
  $product_list2 = array(0 => "");
  $sql = mysql_query ('SELECT * FROM sanpham ORDER BY id DESC');
  $product_count = mysql_num_rows ($sql);

  $a=0;
  if ($product_count >0) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($sql)){
  $ID = $row["ID"];
  $ID2 = $row["ID2"];
  $a++;
  $product_name = $row["productname"];
  $price = $row["Price"];
  $product_list .= '<td class="table_cell_sellingsection"><img src="Productimages/'.$ID.'.png" class="imagesproduct" alt="">
  <p>'.$product_name.'&nbsp;</p> <hr> <p class="price_product">Price: '.$price.' vnđ</p> <p> 
  <form name="Addtocart" method="post" action="" >
  <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="'.$ID.'">
  <button class="Button-Addtocart" type="submit" onclick="Add_to_Cart()"> <img class="Add_to_cart" src="images/Addtocart.png" width="65" height="26" alt="">   </button> 
  </form>

  <button id ="button-click" type="submit" class="Button-detail" onclick="changediv()">
  <img class="Button-detail-img" src="images/Detail.gif" width="70" height="26" alt=""></p></td>';

  array_push($product_list2, '<div id="div_top1">
  <div class="div-detail">
  <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="4">
  <tr>
  <td class="headname" height="55" colspan="3">'.$product_name.'</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td width="35%" height="273" rowspan="1"><img class="imagesproduct1" src="Barefoot_2014_DVD_Cover.jpg" width="1024"             height="687" alt=""></td>
  <td class="info-more" width="65%">
    PRICE: VNĐ <hr>
    DESCRIPTION <hr>
  <span class="des-info">Chất liệu: Cotton<br>

    Thoáng mát phù hợp với mọi lứa tuổi
    Đảm bảo chất lượng cao, số lượng có hạn, click để mua!</span>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="size-product" width="35%" height="57">
  <span style="padding-right: 30px;">SIZE</span>  X XL XXL

  </td>
  <td><form name="Addtocart" method="post" action="" >
  <input type="hidden" name="pid2" value="'.$ID2.'">
   <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="'.$ID.'">
   <button class="Button-Addtocart" type="submit" onclick="Add_to_Cart()"> <img class="Add_to_cart" src="images/Addtocart.png" width="65" height="26" alt=""></button> 
   </form>
  <button id ="button-click" type="submit" class="Button-detail" onclick="changediv()"><img class="Button-detail-img" src="images/Detail.gif" width="70" height="26" alt=""> </td></tr></table></div></div>');}   } else {echo "You have no product";}
  ```